# Do bootstrap and kendo css file links need to be placed on a page in a certain order to make them work together?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

Do bootstrap and kendo css file links need to be placed on a page in a certain order to make them work together? I've noticed that each time I add either one of them to the same page, I get unexpected behavior, such as characters become small or certain buttons become blue instead of orange.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Make sure you are using the kendo.common-bootstrap.css instead of the kendo.common.css

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They have to be in specific order, bootstrap overrides after kendo base for it to work properly.